# How to get Elmah working with ASP.NET and IIS 5.1 URL Routing

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, elmah

I am having issues with regards to running my ASP.NET MVC application thru my local IIS 5.1 web server.  I believe these issues are related to IgnoreRoutes, but I can't seem to craft an IgnoreRoute such that it resolves the problem.

**Problem:**

I am able to view my elmah error page (localhost/mvcapplication1/elmah.axd), however, the CSS is missing and none of the links work.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1) Create an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Application

2) Add Elmah.  Download the assemblies, add them to your project and use the steps from [Elmah Setup Instructions](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC)

3) Switch your application to 'Use Local IIS Web Server' from Property Pages --> Web

4) Add the wildcard mapping.  That is, open up IIS, go to properties --> Virtual directory --> Configuration --> Add:  Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll Extension: .* Limit To: GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG Uncheck 'Check that file exists'.

5) Verify that `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` exists in the RegisterRoutes of your Global.aspx.  By the way, I have also tried `routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");`

Now.. run the app and bring up localhost/mvcapplication1/elmah.axd.

No CSS and links are broken.

If I remove the wildcard mapping, all is fine, but then the application URL routing no longer works.  I understand that, but I should be able to pull up the elmah.axd with the proper IgnoreRoute scheme.

Thoughts??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add FixIIS5xWildcardMapping module to your web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="FixIIS5xWildcardMapping" type="Elmah.FixIIS5xWildcardMappingModule, Elmah"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: I had the same issue too. Running XP with IIS5.1 and this sorted the little swine. I stumbled on this question in the midst of all the IIS7 solutions :)

Comment: This works for mod_mono as well. Routing past elmah.axd/? would puke with 404s. Thanks