# How to secure Elmah working with ASP.NET and IIS 5.1 URL Routing

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, elmah

This question builds on the following question:
[How to get Elmah working with ASP.NET and IIS 5.1 URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982267/how-to-get-elmah-working-with-asp-net-and-iis-5-1-url-routing)

The solution suggested there worked, as long as elmah.axd is off of the root of the site.  What if you want to secure the site as blogged here:
[Securely Implement ELMAH For Plug And Play Error Logging](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx)?

Moving elmah.axd to /admin/elmah.axd breaks the Fix IIS 5x Wildcard Mapping Module.

My workaround was just to secure "elmah.axd" instead of "admin," like:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Although this works, I feel that there's got to be a more elegant solution.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same solution I use in my projects. Anything else more "elegant" would be a lot more complicated and unnecessary.

It does the trick and is simple, I'd keep it like that if I was you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also rename elmah.axd to something less obvious. The name is configurable in your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Todd Smith's answer:

If you want to rename your elmah.axd, all you need to do is to change the name in the handler.

```
<add name="Elmah" path="ANY_NAME_YOU_LIKE.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
```